# Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath'

Tags: android, gradle

Hello I am facing Unable to resolve dependency error in my android studio & i`ve tried it all e.g deleting .gradle folder updating gradle to 4.5 reinstalll android studio and many more solution but I still have this error pls help 
 **Here are gradle files**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pk.com.sngpl.gasiscash"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
            maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
            maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
            jcenter()
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.2.2@aar'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk:android-morphing-button:98a4986e56' // commit hash
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
    compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.8.4'
}
```

**Here is another one**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Here is gradle wrapper properties**

```
 #Tue Dec 19 19:38:03 PKT 2017
    distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    distributionPath=wrapper/dists
    zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.5.1-all.zip
```

**& this is gradle.properties**

```
[# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true][1]
```

Comment: show whole error first ?

Comment: you've added 'allprojects repositories' inside app gradle. thats reason for error. add them in module gradle file

Answer (score 0):

App gradle :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pk.com.sngpl.gasiscash"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.2.2@aar'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk:android-morphing-button:98a4986e56' // commit hash
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
    compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.8.4'
}
```

main gradle :

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
            maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
            maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
            jcenter()
        }
    }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Try this and let me know..

Comment: Please explain what you did